# How to annotate top two corners of the rectangle on the top most facet only in ggplot

Tags: ggplot2, facet-wrap

I am trying to annotate the top two corners of the rectangle on the top most facet only but the following code is not producing the desired output, it is not throwing any error either. It just plots the data without text annotations. Any suggestions?

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1234)
data <- cbind(1:50, matrix(rnorm(150), 50, 3))
data[,2] <- data[,2] *100
d <- c()
for (i in 2:ncol(data)) {
  d <- rbind(d, data[, c(1, i)])
}
fac <-
  c(rep("y1", nrow(data)), rep("y2", nrow(data)), rep("y3", nrow(data)))
d <- as.data.frame(cbind(d, fac))
colnames(d)[1:2] <- c("X", "Y")
d$X <- as.numeric(d$X)
d$Y <- as.numeric(d$Y)
d$fac <- as.factor(d$fac)
xa <- 10
xb <- 20
ndata <- dim(d)[1]
p <- ggplot(data = d, aes(x = X, y = Y)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ d$fac,
             scales = "free_y",
             ncol = 1,
             strip.position = "left",
             labeller = as_labeller(c(y1 = "y1", y2 = "y2", y3 = "y3"))) +
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text.x = element_blank(),
        strip.text.y = element_text(size = 15, face = "bold"),
        strip.placement = "outside",
        axis.text = element_text(size = 12),
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 15, face = "bold")) +
  geom_rect(
    xmin = rep(xa, ndata),
    xmax = rep(xb, ndata),
    ymin = rep(-Inf, ndata),
    ymax = rep(+Inf, ndata),
    alpha = 0.002,
    fill = "blue"
  )

temp <- d$Y[d$fac == "y1"]
ann_text <- data.frame(x = c(xa, xb),
                       y = max(temp),
                       fac = as.factor("y1"),
                       label = c("E1", "E2"))
p + geom_text(data = ann_text, aes(x = x, y = y, label = label), color = 'black')

print(p)
```

Comment: You should use `p <- p + geom_text(...)` to save adding the layer to the plot.

Comment: Cool, this worked! thanks. Why don't you post the answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing to `facet_wrap(~ fac, ...` gets the labels rendered:

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1234)
data <- cbind(1:50, matrix(rnorm(150), 50, 3))
data[,2] <- data[,2] *100
d <- c()
for (i in 2:ncol(data)) {
  d <- rbind(d, data[, c(1, i)])
}
fac <-
  c(rep("y1", nrow(data)), rep("y2", nrow(data)), rep("y3", nrow(data)))
d <- as.data.frame(cbind(d, fac))
colnames(d)[1:2] <- c("X", "Y")
d$X <- as.numeric(d$X)
d$Y <- as.numeric(d$Y)
d$fac <- as.factor(d$fac)
xa <- 10
xb <- 20
ndata <- dim(d)[1]
p <- ggplot(data = d, aes(x = X, y = Y)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ fac,
             scales = "free_y",
             ncol = 1,
             strip.position = "left",
             labeller = as_labeller(c(y1 = "y1", y2 = "y2", y3 = "y3"))) +
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text.x = element_blank(),
        strip.text.y = element_text(size = 15, face = "bold"),
        strip.placement = "outside",
        axis.text = element_text(size = 12),
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 15, face = "bold")) +
  geom_rect(
    xmin = rep(xa, ndata),
    xmax = rep(xb, ndata),
    ymin = rep(-Inf, ndata),
    ymax = rep(+Inf, ndata),
    alpha = 0.002,
    fill = "blue"
  )

temp <- d$Y[d$fac == "y1"]


ann_text <- data.frame(x = c(xa, xb),
                       y = max(temp),
                       fac = as.factor("y1"),
                       label = c("E1", "E2"))

p + geom_text(data = ann_text, aes(x = x, y = y, label = label), color = 'black')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Session info

```r
sessioninfo::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value
#>  version  R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22)
#>  os       macOS Big Sur/Monterey 10.16
#>  system   x86_64, darwin17.0
#>  ui       X11
#>  language (EN)
#>  collate  en_GB.UTF-8
#>  ctype    en_GB.UTF-8
#>  tz       Europe/London
#>  date     2022-05-23
#>  pandoc   2.17.1.1 @ /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/quarto/bin/ (via rmarkdown)
#> 
#> ─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  package     * version date (UTC) lib source
#>  assertthat    0.2.1   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  backports     1.4.1   2021-12-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  broom         0.8.0   2022-04-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  cellranger    1.1.0   2016-07-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  cli           3.3.0   2022-04-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  colorspace    2.0-3   2022-02-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  crayon        1.5.1   2022-03-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  curl          4.3.2   2021-06-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  DBI           1.1.2   2021-12-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  dbplyr        2.1.1   2021-04-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  digest        0.6.29  2021-12-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  dplyr       * 1.0.9   2022-04-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  ellipsis      0.3.2   2021-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  evaluate      0.15    2022-02-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  fansi         1.0.3   2022-03-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  farver        2.1.0   2021-02-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  fastmap       1.1.0   2021-01-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  forcats     * 0.5.1   2021-01-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  fs            1.5.2   2021-12-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  generics      0.1.2   2022-01-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  ggplot2     * 3.3.6   2022-05-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  glue          1.6.2   2022-02-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  gtable        0.3.0   2019-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  haven         2.5.0   2022-04-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  highr         0.9     2021-04-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  hms           1.1.1   2021-09-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  htmltools     0.5.2   2021-08-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  httr          1.4.3   2022-05-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  jsonlite      1.8.0   2022-02-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  knitr         1.39    2022-04-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  labeling      0.4.2   2020-10-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  lifecycle     1.0.1   2021-09-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  lubridate     1.8.0   2021-10-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  magrittr      2.0.3   2022-03-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  mime          0.12    2021-09-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  modelr        0.1.8   2020-05-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  munsell       0.5.0   2018-06-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  pillar        1.7.0   2022-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  pkgconfig     2.0.3   2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  purrr       * 0.3.4   2020-04-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  R.cache       0.15.0  2021-04-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  R.methodsS3   1.8.1   2020-08-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  R.oo          1.24.0  2020-08-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  R.utils       2.11.0  2021-09-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  R6            2.5.1   2021-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  readr       * 2.1.2   2022-01-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  readxl        1.4.0   2022-03-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  reprex        2.0.1   2021-08-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  rlang         1.0.2   2022-03-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  rmarkdown     2.14    2022-04-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  rstudioapi    0.13    2020-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  rvest         1.0.2   2021-10-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  scales        1.2.0   2022-04-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  sessioninfo   1.2.2   2021-12-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  stringi       1.7.6   2021-11-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  stringr     * 1.4.0   2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  styler        1.7.0   2022-03-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  tibble      * 3.1.7   2022-05-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  tidyr       * 1.2.0   2022-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  tidyselect    1.1.2   2022-02-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  tidyverse   * 1.3.1   2021-04-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  tzdb          0.3.0   2022-03-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  utf8          1.2.2   2021-07-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  vctrs         0.4.1   2022-04-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  withr         2.5.0   2022-03-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  xfun          0.31    2022-05-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  xml2          1.3.3   2021-11-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  yaml          2.3.5   2022-02-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#> 
#>  [1] /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library
#> 
#> ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

Comment: thanks for sharing your solution. unfortunately, it did not work on my PC. I am using ggplot2=3.3.6 on R v4.2.0.

Comment: I've added my session info, and the above is running in a fresh r session. Don't forget to remove your `print(p)` which is printing p without the `geom_text`.

Comment: (`geom_label` could also be a nice alternative to `geom_text` in this example, but that's just personal choice.)

Comment: Cool! problem is resolved after applying the suggestions from teunbrand about print(p) on your code